# mysql master/slave replication issue: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, openjpa, master-slave

I have spent a lot of time but could not figure it out. I know that, If I use the `BasicDataSource` then the configuration needs to passed in the `openjpa.ConnectionProperties` property. The `openjpa.ConnectionProperties` is comma (,) separated properties which get mapped to the [`DataSource`](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_dbsetup.html) instance. Now [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) also expects the hosts in comma (,) separated format. So not able to figure out, How do I create an `DataSource` with `MySQL replication`?*

I am trying to setup master/slave db with openjpa and it fails with the below exception while creating the `createEntityManager()` from the `EntityManagerFactory`.

Here is the code:

```
String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306,slave:3306/db";
String user = "abc";
String password = "123";
String connProps = "DriverClassName={0},Url={1},Username={2},Password={3}";

public void method() {
    connProps = MessageFormat.format(connProps, driver, url, user, password);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("openjpa.ConnectionProperties", connProps);
    props.setProperty("openjpa.ConnectionDriverName", "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource");
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql", props);
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
}
```

I getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.4.1-r422266:1730418 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Must specify at least one slave host to connect to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:603)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1520)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:533)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:458)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:121)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:967)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:958)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:642)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:202)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at ExampleJPA.method(ExampleJPA.java:22)
    at ExampleJPA.main(ExampleJPA.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Must specify at least one slave host to connect to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:86)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:90)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Must specify at least one slave host to connect to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connectReplicationConnection(NonRegisteringDriver.java:414)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:313)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 27 more
```

The master slave setup of the database is seems to working fine. I have checked the connectivity of the slave from master through telnet.

Comment: do you have the same db instance on both servers? same `oozie` ?

Comment: Yes. I have same database available on both mysql setup. I have setup the master and slave mysql correctly, because If I just work with the master database, the new data is automatically, getting replicated in the slave. The issue comes when I use the above configuration, with replication feature.

Comment: what happens if you try to set the properties separated, i.e using `props.setProperty()` for parameters `openjpa.ConnectionDriverName`, `openjpa.ConnectionURL`, `openjpa.ConnectionUserName`, `openjpa.ConnectionPassword`, not using 1 string with 3 params (connProps)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution seems silly after spending so much time on it. I got this working. I need to pass the jdbc url with double quotes (`"jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306,slave:3306/db"`) and then works fine.

I will provide the more information soon.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC URL passed to MySQL driver is not what you think is.
MySQL driver is trying to parse URL and split it using `","` token

```
    if ((hostStuff != null) && (hostStuff.trim().length() > 0)) {
        List<String> hosts = StringUtils.split(hostStuff, ",", ALLOWED_QUOTES, ALLOWED_QUOTES, false);
```

but it can't find more then one, so it yields error:

```
    int numHosts = Integer.parseInt(parsedProps.getProperty(NUM_HOSTS_PROPERTY_KEY));

    if (numHosts < 2) {
        throw SQLError.createSQLException("Must specify at least one slave host to connect to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality",
                SQLError.SQL_STATE_INVALID_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTE, null);
    }
```

Most probably JDBC URL is modified/broken by DBCP or OpenJPA.

Link to [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.29/com/mysql/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java#454)

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right. It is passing only the first host to the MySQL Driver.

Comment: nice find :) i used this info to suggest a sol. but not sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think the error's reason is using `openjpa.ConnectionProperties` to set properties in one string, with a comma as separator, while the property `URL` have a value that also is comma separated

as per @rkosegi answer, something is messed up related to the comma "," to solve that i think you have to use separated properties not 1 string. or at least consider removing `Url={1},` and set that using `openjpa.ConnectionURL`

here is what i think you need to do in `method()`:

```
props.setProperty("openjpa.ConnectionDriverName", "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource");
props.setProperty("openjpa.ConnectionUserName", user);
props.setProperty("openjpa.ConnectionPassword", password);
props.setProperty("openjpa.ConnectionURL", url);
```

remove the line:

```
props.setProperty("openjpa.ConnectionProperties", connProps);
```

don't use `String connProps = "DriverClassName={0},Url={1},Username={2},Password={3}";` anymore.

P.S: just a heads-up you are using `"org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"` not `driver` parameter. just make sure that is what you want.

Comment: This is will not work with `DataSource` instance. Because JPA internally uses the `openjpa.ConnectionProperties` to initialize the `DataSource` instance. http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_dbsetup.html

Comment: @YoungHobbit hmmm, not sure about this, but logically i think when `ConnectionProperties` got splitted on comma, the hosts (url) list got messed up?!

Comment: thats why i suggested not using it

Comment: See, If I don't use the `DataSource` and use `ReplicatoinDriver` with individual properties it connects. But How Can I get it done with DataSource instance, because application is already using the DataSource, Simple connection might require a lot refactoring.

Comment: i did not use any of this before, but have you tried `BasicDataSource` with individual properties? just curious will you get an exception?

Comment: Yes, I get an exception, but a different one. `Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'` This is I guess, how the ConnectionProperties is parsed and used to initialize the DataSource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108371/discussion-between-younghobbit-and-yazan).